# Shared calendars no longer show up in the sidebar

Tags: google-calendar

My shared calendars no longer show up in the sidebar on Google Calendar. All of them show up in the calendar itself and I cannot see anything but all the colors of the people who are sharing a calendar with. They were showing up and then there are only a couple left there.

How do I get them back?